# sql how to add missing week to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `table` that has this data: Date `when` the employees reported and the week `start-date(Monday)` for that week. Now they did not work all the `dates`.  For example there is no data on week of `christmas`. Is there a way I can add the missing `week`.So, I will still have the week `start-date` for each and every `week`. But the `report-date` can be null.

I cannot declare `variables`

This is what I have

[image]

and this is what i want to add the missing week

[image]

Comment: its unclear what you have asked. does your requirement is a query which generate all week start-dates in a year?

Comment: You need a tallytable with all the dates; you can then `LEFT JOIN` the tallytable to your source table.

Answer (score 1):

Query
**[SQLFIDDLEEXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38bf9/5)**:

```
CREATE TABLE tb 
    (
     d1 date, 
     d2 date
    );

INSERT INTO tb
(d1, d2)
VALUES
('2015-12-10', '2015-12-07'),
('2015-12-15', '2015-12-14'),
('2015-12-29', '2015-12-28'),
('2016-01-05', '2016-01-04');

SET DATEFIRST 1 

INSERT INTO tb
( d1, d2 )
select null, DATEADD(day,number,'2015-01-01')
FROM master..spt_values t1
LEFT JOIN tb t2
ON DATEADD(day,number,'2015-01-01') = t2.d2
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(day,number,'2015-01-01') >= '2015-12-01'
AND DATEADD(day,number,'2015-01-01') <= '2016-01-04'
AND DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,number,'2015-01-01')) = 1
AND t2.d2 is null

SELECT *
FROM tb
```

Result:

```
|         d1 |         d2 |
|------------|------------|
| 2015-12-10 | 2015-12-07 |
| 2015-12-15 | 2015-12-14 |
| 2015-12-29 | 2015-12-28 |
| 2016-01-05 | 2016-01-04 |
|     (null) | 2015-12-21 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Calendar/Weeks table containing all the weeks in the year. This table should be in advance.

You can then make a reference from your data table to this calendar table (by id or week/year).

Your report should be based on the calendar table with an outer join to your data table.

This way your report will contain all weeks even if some weeks don't have any data.

EDIT: You would need a new table like this:

```
Week:
| Start date | End date |
| 12/07/15   | 12/13/15 |
| 12/14/15   | 12/20/15 |
| 12/21/15   | 12/27/15 |
etc...
```

Comment: SELECT P.* from
(select distinct week_start_date
from [project]
union

select distinct AddDays(week_start_date,7)
from [project]
) AS W
LEFT JOIN [project] AS P
ON W.week_start_date=P.week_start_date

Comment: Peter Berggreen , thanks for reply but for how many years will I create this calendar  table

Comment: It will not be a very big table, so you can create a few years ahead if you wan't to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `#weekly_calendar` table contains your valid work weeks (i.e., for Dec 2015). By the way, syntax is for MSSQL. You should specify what database you are using.

You can also dynamically create the calendar on run-time. This is just to show the concept in an easy to understand way.

```
-- week start dates
-- 2015-12-01
-- 2015-12-07
-- 2015-12-14
-- 2015-12-21
-- 2015-12-28

create table #weekly_calendar (
    week_start_date datetime,
    week_end_date datetime
)
```

Assuming that `#report_date` contains the report date of the employee.

```
-- report dates
-- 2015-12-02
-- 2015-12-15
-- 2015-12-29

create table #report_date (
    report_date datetime
)
```

This is how you display the unreported dates.

```
select * from #weekly_calendar w
left join #report_date r
on r.report_date between w.week_start_date and w.week_end_date
```

If you do not have the week_end_date. Again, assuming your work days start from Monday to Friday.

```
select * from #weekly_calendar w
left join #report_date r
on r.report_date between w.week_start_date and DATEADD(dd, 6-(DATEPART(dw, w.week_end_date)), w.week_end_date)
```

[image]